# Redirect url if Contains Query String to new URL and Pass Sting

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, redirect, yoast

I have a url https://example.com/registration-free/?member_id=1234&code=0e9236c500453e3c624ca96939f8aabf and this is a conformation link for a subscription process, but I want to locate this to another page and pass the variables, using regex in either htaccess or yoast pro for wordpress

the new page would be https://example.com/registration-step3/?member_id=1234&code=0e9236c500453e3c624ca96939f8aabf

But if someone goes to the page https://example.com/registration-free/ and there is no query string I don't want to redirect them.

Is this possible, so to clarify, if the initial page has no query string it doesn't redirect, but if a query string is present it redirects and passes the variables to the new url, using htacces or regex in wordpress yoast pro

Comment: write it, so that the regex only fires, if there is a `?member_id`, remember to escape the `?`

Comment: like this : https://regex101.com/r/DqOb0o/6 -

Comment: Brilliant, that's done the trick, thank you so much for your help

Comment: no problem m8! good luck to ya